# Creating Regex function to identify elements before and after a word

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to develop a regex function to identify words before and after an object of interest. I am working with corpus and will need the function to loop through each document. I can provide a sample text.

```
text <- c('species of cat are endangered', 'house cats require a lot of food', 'some cats prefer to be alone')
```

In this example, I need to collect one to two words before and after the text *cat*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an even simpler way to go about the issue. After stemming the word, I just used the following for loop. Thank you for the responses.

```
 out_all <- list()

 for (i in object) { 
 text <- df$documents[i]
 str_extract_all(text,"([^\\s]+\\s+){2}cat(\\s+[^\\s]+){2}")
 out_all[i] <- str_extract_all(string = text, pattern = "([^\\s]+\\s+){0,2}cat(\\s+ 
 [^\\s]+){0,2}") 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function:

```r
func <- function(txt, ptn, befaft = 1, ...) {
  lapply(strsplit(txt, "\\s+"),
         function(sentence) {
           t(sapply(grep(ptn, sentence, ...),
                    function(ind) {
                      ind <- seq.int(ind - befaft, ind + befaft)
                      ind <- replace(ind, (ind < 1) | (ind > length(sentence)), NA)
                      sentence[ind]
                    }))
         })
}
```

It tries to work through two possibilities:

- `cats?` inside of `befaft` words from the beginning or end, in which case it returns `NA` for the unfillable positions; and
- multiple matches within a single string, in which case it returns multiple batches of words. I've added a test case that includes this.

```r
func(text, "cats?")
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3] 
# [1,] "of" "cat" "are"
# [[2]]
#      [,1]    [,2]   [,3]     
# [1,] "house" "cats" "require"
# [[3]]
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]    
# [1,] "some" "cats" "prefer"
# [[4]]
#      [,1]      [,2]   [,3] 
# [1,] "all"     "cats" "are"
# [2,] "believe" "cats" "are"

func(text, "cats?", befaft = 2)
# [[1]]
#      [,1]      [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]        
# [1,] "species" "of" "cat" "are" "endangered"
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]    [,3]   [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] NA   "house" "cats" "require" "a" 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]     [,5]
# [1,] NA   "some" "cats" "prefer" "to"
# [[4]]
#      [,1]  [,2]      [,3]   [,4]  [,5]     
# [1,] NA    "all"     "cats" "are" "royalty"
# [2,] "and" "believe" "cats" "are" "better"
```

(The `...` in the function allows you to pass arbitrary functions to `grep`, such as `ignore.case`, `fixed`, and `perl`.)

Answer (score -1):

This was fun. You can use the `str_extract_words()` function defined here. It uses the **"(\w)"** regex to get a list of words before and after a `word_pattern` specified by the user. Here the word_pattern will be **"cats?"** to be able to get both **cat** and **cats**.

```r
library(tidyverse)

text <- c('species of cat are endangered', 'house cats require a lot of food', 'some cats prefer to be alone')

str_extract_words <- function(str, word_pattern, n_before = 1, n_after = 1) {
  
  pattern_beffore <- str_dup("(\\w*) ", n_before) %>% str_glue("{word_pattern}")
  pattern_after <- str_dup(" (\\w*)", n_after) %>% str_glue("{word_pattern}", .)
  
  words_before <- text %>% 
    str_extract(pattern_beffore) %>% 
    str_remove(str_glue(" {word_pattern}"))
  
  words_after <- text %>% 
    str_extract(pattern_after) %>% 
    str_remove(str_glue("{word_pattern} "))
  
  list(words_before = words_before, words_after = words_after)
}
```

```r
# defaults to  1 word before and 1 word after the pattern
str_extract_words(text, "cats?")
#> $words_before
#> [1] "of"    "house" "some" 
#> 
#> $words_after
#> [1] "are"     "require" "prefer"

# You can specify the number of words to get
str_extract_words(text, "cats?", n_after = 2)
#> $words_before
#> [1] "of"    "house" "some" 
#> 
#> $words_after
#> [1] "are endangered" "require a"      "prefer to"

# Will output NA when `str` does not have the required number of words
str_extract_words(text, "cats?", n_before = 2)
#> $words_before
#> [1] "species of" NA           NA          
#> 
#> $words_after
#> [1] "are"     "require" "prefer"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

This pattern matches 1 or 2 words before or after cat or cats as well as 1 or two words after.

```
library(stringr)
pattern="((\\w+) ){1,2}(cat|cats)( (\\w+)){1,2}"
str_match_all(text, pattern)

[[1]]
     [,1]                            [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5]          [,6]        
[1,] "species of cat are endangered" "of " "of" "cat" " endangered" "endangered"

[[2]]
     [,1]                   [,2]     [,3]    [,4]   [,5] [,6]
[1,] "house cats require a" "house " "house" "cats" " a" "a" 

[[3]]
     [,1]                  [,2]    [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  [,6]
[1,] "some cats prefer to" "some " "some" "cats" " to" "to"

str_locate_all(text, pattern)

[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     1  29

[[2]]
     start end
[1,]     1  20

[[3]]
     start end
[1,]     1  19

str_view_all(text, pattern)
```